# When radio selected, change image src on vue.js version2

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to change image and that trigger an image update.

This is for example 
http://jsbin.com/kuluyike/3/edit?html,js,output

```
  <div id="colorPicker">
    <img v-attr="src:color" alt="{{color}}">
    <ul>
      <li v-repeat="colors">
        <label>
          <input type="radio" id="{{name}}" name="color" v-model="color" value="{{image}}">
          {{name}}
        </label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>


  var cp = new Vue({
    el: '#colorPicker',

    data: {
      colors: [
        {
          name: 'red',
          image: 'red.jpg'
        },
        {
          name: 'pink',
          image: 'pink.jpg'
        },
        {
          name: 'blue',
          image: 'blue.jpg'
        }
      ]
    }
  });
```

But this is not working on Vue.js version 2.x

How do I change the code so working based on version 2.x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [Vue 2.0, the syntax has changed for attributes](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Attributes), this means, you now have to declare your attributed as the following:

```
<img :src="color" :alt="color">
<input type="radio" :id="name" :name="color" v-model="color" :value="image">
```

In [Vue 2.0, the syntax for loops has changed from `v-repeat` to `v-for`:](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#v-for):

```
<li v-for="(colorInfo, index) in colors">
<input type="radio" :id="colorInfo.name" name="color" v-model="color" :value="colorInfo.image">
```

In Vue 2.0 development mode, a warning is emitted when you access an undeclared property

```
data: {
    // ...
    color: undefined,
},
```

```js
var cp = new Vue({
    el: '#colorPicker',

    data: {
      color: undefined,
      colors: [
        {
          name: 'red',
          image: 'red.jpg'
        },
        {
          name: 'pink',
          image: 'pink.jpg'
        },
        {
          name: 'blue',
          image: 'blue.jpg'
        }
      ]
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>


<div id="colorPicker">
    <img :src="color" :alt="color">
    <ul>
      <li v-for="(colorInfo, index) in colors">
        <label>
          <input type="radio" :id="colorInfo.name" name="color" v-model="color" :value="colorInfo.image">
          {{colorInfo.name}}
        </label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

See also: [Migration from Vue 1.x - Vuejs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html)

Comment: Ferrybig //  Thanks for your detail explanation. Can I give you additional question ? I want to show first image(red) as default ,  How to add the code? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can use `v-for` here for looping in Vue 2.x like:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#colorPicker',
  data: {
    color: null,
    colors: [{
        name: 'red',
        image: 'red.jpg'
      },
      {
        name: 'pink',
        image: 'pink.jpg'
      },
      {
        name: 'blue',
        image: 'blue.jpg'
      }
    ]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="colorPicker">
  <img :src="color" :alt="color" v-if="color" />
  <ul>
    <li v-for="c in colors">
      <label>
          <input type="radio" name="color" v-model="color" :value="c.image"/>
          {{c.name}}
        </label>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <p v-if="color"><b>Selected image name: </b> {{color}}</p>
</div>
```